# Crontab running a python script with parameters

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to figure out why my crontab is not running my python scripts, i suspect it is due to the parameters i have:

This is what it looks like:

```
0       3       * * *   root    /usr/bin/python && /usr/bin/python -q /root/tools/script.py parm1 parm2 2>&1 >>/var/log/python-tools.log
```

So basically i can run this in the terminal:

```
$ python script.py parm1 parm2
```

But when i try with the above line in the crontab it does not work

Comment: Why do you have `/usr/bin/python &&` at the beginning?

Comment: I can't find the `-q` option in the Python documentation. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Have you checked root's email for error messages from `cron`?

Comment: hmm good question, copied from another line forgot to remove...

Comment: Which part, the `/usr/bin/python &&` or the `-q` option?

Comment: Maybe that was supposed to be `test -e /usr/bin/python &&`, which makes sure that the python program exists before trying to use it.

Comment: @bamar i think you are right, this is properbly why it was added in the beginning, but since i know it exist, i just removed it for now... so now it looks like this:
0       3       * * *   root    /usr/bin/python /root/tools/script.py dk 0 2>&1 >>/var/log/python-tools.log

Comment: That looks like it should work.

Comment: It did...! worked like a charm, can you create an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-q` is an invalid argument to `python`. And you shouldn't have `/usr/bin/python &&` before it.

```
0 3 * * * root /usr/bin/python /root/tools/script.py parm1 parm2 2>&1 >>/var/log/python-tools.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, must this script be run from root? It's generally a bad idea.

Secondly the use of &&, this means it will run the command after only if the command before exits with success, since in the first command you are only running python and it's not actually doing anything you are unlikely to get an exit with success code.

Comment: It's writing to a log file in `/var/log`, this typically requires root permission.

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the permissions for that particular log file? Or perhaps use another location and log file that doesn't need root? That way you wouldn't need root for the whole script

Comment: His script is also located in `/root/tools`. My guess is the script is doing some system maintenance task.

Comment: yeah root is a bad choice i agree, but Barmar is right, its required in this case

I removed the && now since you are also right this step is not needed actually... 

This line was copied from another crontab where it was a PHP script which was running, and did not really considered this :)